# How does the iPhone round when calculating averages in the Health App?

Tags: iphone, health.app

Tracking steps month by month and am curious how the app rounds numbers.

For example, a calculated average of 99.53 does not round up to 100, but shows as 99.

This is deep in the weeds, but wanted to know how it works.

Comment: isn't it better to tell you less than more?  i.e. you averaged 99 or nearly 100 rather than 100 (when you didn't do 100?)?

Comment: @MrR. I make no judgement on the value of how the software rounds, just want to understand the how.  The rounding rules I'm familiar with would round 99.53 up to 100.